# Find limit for $\frac{1+2+4+...+2^{n-1}}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am supposed to find the $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+2+4+...+2^{n-1}}{2^n}$ using limit identities. I know that the limit is supposed to be 1, but am unsure how to get there. I have tried splitting up the limit to multiple smaller limits but so far have been unsuccessful.

Comment: The numerator is a geometric series, so can be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to find a nicer expression for the numerator. In particular, you can show $1 + 2 + 4 + \dots + 2^{n-1} = 2^n - 1$ (why?). From there, can you see why the limit should be $1$?

Comment: So from this I can say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1-0=1$ right?

Comment: Yeah, looks good to me!